# Union of translates of a set of positive measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let A $ \subset [0,1]$ be a measurable set of positive Lebesgue measure. Then does the set $ \cup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} (A+r) \mod1 $ necessarily have Lebesgue measure 1? 
I know A can be approximated by intervals and if B is finite union of intervals with $ m(A \triangle B) < \epsilon $ then $ \cup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} (B+r) $ has Lebesgue measure 1 (in fact we need only to take finitely many rationals in above union) but this alone does not help me to conclude the statement for A.

Comment: Hint: Say $0<\lambda<1$ and $\epsilon>0$. There exists an interval $I$ such that $|I|<\epsilon$ and $|A\cap I|>\lambda |I|$.